# Why spring-cloud-config sample test needs to spin a config-server?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I want to write unit/integration tests for my config server so I checked [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-sample/src/test/java/sample/ApplicationTests.java) link. There's a class annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and also a function `startConfigServer()` inside annotated with `@BeforeClass`. Why exactly is this function needed because there's the `@SpringBootTest` annotation?

And what other unit test cases and integration tests can I write for the config server? I'm also using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka and Spring Cloud Bus, along with Spring Security basic authentication enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring-cloud-bus** is a mechanism for mutiple application nodes to communicate, offering the ability to broadcast events.
This communication in place, the application can use it, for example, to get the configuration from a ***configuration-server*** in a dynamic way (a change in configuration will lead to broadcasting the appropriate event).

So when testing such an application, the test must first provide a ***configuration-server*** to get the configuration from, hence the `startConfigServer()` method in the example you linked.

[Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2017/10/24/how-to-test-spring-cloud-stream-applications-part-i) references **spring-cloud-stream-test-support** to ease testing of this messaging abstraction, but I have not used it myself.

However, an other way to test this is to mock all accesses to this ***configuration-server*** (through **HTTP** and **spring-cloud-stream** underlying broker).

Here is an [example of all the mocking stuff](https://github.com/fridujo/rabbitmq-mock/blob/master/src/it/spring_cloud_bus/src/test/java/com/github/fridujo/rabbitmq/mock/integration/springcloudbus/ConfigClientTest.java) (using RabbitMQ, but the idea will be the same with Kafka).

Testing the ***configuration-server*** is just the other way around (modify a configuration file and assert that a message is published on the underlying broker).

For the record, I am not sure that **spring-cloud-bus** can be used with Kafka, as the official documentation says only AMQP (0.9) is supported : https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus